# SQL Server Non Clustered Index creation timeout on large table (40 million rows)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, timeout, non-clustered-index

Up until recently, I've been creating indexes *(<20s)* and running heavy queries *(<10s)* relatively quickly on a database containing tables that have up to about 10-12 million rows each.

My newest database has tables with up to 40 million rows each and both my index creation and querying is suffering tremendously.

- Index creation is timing out (even with my Tools > Options > Designers > Table and Database Designers > Transaction Timeout being upped to 120 seconds)
- Queries that had been taking me 10 seconds are now taking 40-50 seconds in SQL Server Management Studio (which is logical), HOWEVER:

  - **Those same queries which had been taking 5-10 seconds each using library(RODBC) and sqlQuery() through R are now taking around 4-5 minutes each.**

I'm working on an i7, recently upgraded to SQL Server Management Studio Enterprise (but the issue was occurring prior to upgrade), and I need these queries running at least semi-optimally.

Each query pulls about 200,000 values, but needs to traverse the entire table; thus, a non-clustered index appeared to make sense, but index creation is timing out.

**What have I already done?**:

- Upped the Transaction Timeout from 30 seconds to 120 seconds.
- Increased the Index Creation Memory (Server Properties > Memory) from 0 to 33000.
- Increased Minimum Memory per Query from 1024 to 3500.
- Created a miniature version of a populated table (re: 4 million rows):
- Query time is optimal. (retrieving 40,000 rows (10%), ~2sec)
- Index creation is optimal. (<10s)

I'm not sure where the bottleneck is occurring, any ideas?

Comment: Increase the timeout to something like 20 minutes and see if that works.

Comment: When you are creating the index, look at the wait stats. This will at least tell you where to start looking.